# Obtaining stray text adjacent to selected radio button using xpath in watir

Tags: xpath, watir

I have some stray text next to radio buttons in a radio button group. I tried to obtain it using xpath and watir, but I had no luck with it. Here's some sample HTML for it

```
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
 <input type="radio" name="options" value="No">No <br />
 <input type="radio" name="options" value="Yes">Yes <br />
 <input type="radio" name="options" value="Maybe">Maybe <br />
</body> 
</html>
```

I can obtain the selected radio button using xpath by

```
selectedRadio = browser.radio(:xpath,"//input[@checked and @name='options']")
```

How can I obtain say Yes, No, Maybe if the corresponding radio buttons are selected? I also tried to obtain it using Watir, but the .text method would not work on the Watir::RadioButton object which would be true since the texts are stray texts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That HTML given is not well-formed XML, so I think the expression will depend on how Waitr parses the input. If it thinks that the text is a child of the `input` elements, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" checked="checked" value="No">No </input><br />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="Yes">Yes </input><br />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="Maybe">Maybe </input><br />
```

Then use this expression:

```
//input[@checked and @name='options']/text()
```

If, on the other hand, it automatically closes the `input` and treats the text as a sibling, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" checked="checked" value="No"/>No <br />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="Yes"/>Yes <br />
<input type="radio" name="options" value="Maybe"/>Maybe <br />
```

Then use the following expression:

```
//input[@checked and @name='options']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

My guess is that this second one is the correct one, since you already said that `.text` did not work.

Comment: The second answer is correct according to Xpath, but for some reason in Watir it keeps on returning a nil. Mostly the stray text is not resolved in a tag of its own and thus, it keeps on returning a nil

Answer (score 0):

Ask the developer to make the page more testable by putting the text associated with the radio button inside a [label](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) associated with the button via an ID value

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" />
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" />
  <label for="female">Female</label>
</form>
```

Then you can get the ID for the selected button, and find the associated label text fairly easily.

Seriously, it's a likely a lot easier for them to do that than it is for you to have to deal with sloppy page code.  It also offers them a lot more formatting options (via CSS) to have that text inside a label container.  Win all around.

Comment: I would have developed the page the same way, but apparently its some legacy code which my team doesn't want to change for no apparent reason